# Is the bottom of a lattice an atom?

Tags: lattice-orders

I am looking at the *Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics* $4$th edition edited by David Nelson, studying it as a course of self-study.

Let $L = (S, \vee, \wedge, \preccurlyeq)$ be a lattice.

The definition of the **bottom** of $L$ is defined as either:

- the smallest element of $S$ w.r.t. $\preccurlyeq$

or:

- the identity element of $S$ w.r.t. $\vee$, where $\vee$ is the join operation.

Let us denote $\bot$ as the bottom of $L$.

Now, looking at the abovementioned *Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics*, the definition of an **atom** of $S$ is given as an element $A$ of $S$ such that:

- $\forall B \in S: B \prec A \implies B = \bot$

where $B \prec A$ denotes that $B \preccurlyeq A$ such that $B \ne A$.

But where does that leave $\bot$ itself?

By definition, there are no elements $B$ of $S$ such that $B \prec \bot$.

Hence vacuously:

- $B \prec \bot \implies B = \bot$

and so, vacuously, $\bot$ is indeed an atom of $L$.

Is it a commonplace to need to specify that an atom also needs to be specified as to be an element of $S$ which is **not the bottom**?

That is, is this an omission (that is, a mistake) in *Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics* that the reader needs to be aware of?

Or is the bottom of a lattice also classed as an atom?

Comment: No, the bottom, when it exists, the the least element. An atom, if it exists (and then, there must exist the bottom) is an element that sits just above the bottom (meaning, above the bottom, but no element in between). For example, in a power-set lattice, the bottom is the empty set, and the atoms are the singletons.

Comment: So the definition you present is correct: $a$ is atom if $\bot < a$ but for every $b$ in the lattice, if $b < a$ then $b = \bot$.

Comment: @amrsa But that is not the definition I present. I do not specify that $\bot < a$. This is, I believe, an omission in the source work.

Comment: You are right. I overlooked part of your post. So **if** that's indeed the definition in that Dictionary of Mathematics, it's wrong.